# Need some advice on split() method in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I am writing a program in which I have to split String. Suppose my String is:

LXI H, 2000H, MOV M A

How to split it using split function in Java. Please reply soon.

Comment: That is very good question! Nobody ever did something like that! I wish there wwere some example on the interwebs...

Comment: On which character do you want to split the string?

Comment: I would say [read the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Comment: I want all the different WORD except for comma and Spaces

Comment: What is your expected output and - as @mok said - on which character do you want to do the split

Comment: I love how welcoming Stackoverflow is to members who happen be unaware of the website's guidelines.

Comment: output should be:
LXI
H
2000h
MOV
M
A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that you want to split by the comma then this will make it

```
String toSplit = "LXI H, 2000H, MOV M A";
// this is a regular expression, you should study regular expressions too 
String[] split = toSplit.replace(",", "").split(" +"); 
for (String s : split)
   System.out.println(s);
```

Read the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class in the java API

Comment: Please help me in removing spaces to: For example between LXI and H.

Comment: you want to split lxi and h too ?

Comment: You definitelly need to provide more information in your question and provide what excatly have you tried already and what is your expected output

Comment: Stackoverflow is not good for things that are better answered in a tutorial like format

Comment: Please help! Remove spaces too.

Comment: Its done now. But I will have to downvote your question because of what I explained to you

Comment: Definitelly otherwise you will be banned from making questions here

Comment: Can you please help me in the following line:
String[] split = toSplit.replace(",", "").split(" +"); 
What is the work of " +" inside split?

Comment: it's a regular expresssion http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/

Answer (score 0):

To split by comma, use

`String str = "LXI H, 2000H, MOV M A";
String[] parts = string.split(",");
//for each index
System.out.println(parts[index]);`

Comment: Please help me in removing spaces to: For example between LXI and H.

Comment: Split the str by space and then concatenate together.

`String str = "LXI H, 2000H, MOV M A";

String[] parts = string.split(" ");

String strWithoutSpaces="";

for(int i=0;i<parts.size;i++)
{
strWithoutSpaces+=parts[i];
}
`

Answer (score 0):

To split the string on "space":

```
String s = "LXI H, 2000H, MOV M A";
String[] tmp = s.split(" ");
for(String str: tmp)
    System.out.println(str);
```

To split the string on any whitespace:

```
s.split("\\s+");
```

To split the string on any whitespace and comma:

```
s.split(",|\\s+");
```

To learn more about `split()` method, you may read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) tutorial.